# Dictionary with words as the key and frequencies as the value and finding the highest value in the dictionary with the same length of letters

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

The function prints the keyword length, then prints a sorted list of all the dictionary keywords of the required length, which have the highest frequency, followed by the frequency.  For example, the following code:

```
word_frequencies = {"and":15,  "whale":7,  "frog":7,  "cat":15,  "fish":1,  "dog":2,  "pig":15,  "stork":1,  "rat":15,  "bird":7}
print_most_frequent(word_frequencies, 3)
print_most_frequent(word_frequencies, 4)
print_most_frequent(word_frequencies, 5)
```

prints out:

```
3 letter keywords: ['and', 'cat', 'pig', 'rat'] 15
4 letter keywords: ['bird', 'frog'] 7
5 letter keywords: ['whale'] 7
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
def print_most_frequent(words_dict, word_len):
    keyword_length = []
    frequency = 0
    for key in words_dict:
        if len(key) == word_len and words_dict[key] >= frequency:
            keyword_length += [key]
            if frequency != words_dict[key]:
                frequency += words_dict[key]
    print (str(word_len) + " letter keywords: " + str(keyword_length) + " " + str(frequency))
```

But this gives me :

```
3 letter keywords: ['dog', 'cat'] 17
4 letter keywords: ['frog', 'bird'] 15
5 letter keywords: ['whale'] 7
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so I know what to do.

I need to sort the dictionary alphabetically so it comes out as:

```
['and', 'cat', 'pig', 'rat']
```

instead of randomizing it.

Comment: Rule of a thumb: do not call variables anything with "length" if they're actually not holding the length of anything (which I'd expect to be a number)

Comment: What is the number at the end meant to be? At first I thought it was the max value of the words but in your second example `bird` has a value of `8` but the number at the end is `7`

Comment: Sorry I meant to put in 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension to create a dictionary with the keys that only have a `len` equal to `word_len`. Then you can get the max values of those items using `max`. Finally you can create a list with only the items that have a frequency equal to the max frequency.

You can use `sorted` to sort the list in alphabetical order.

```
word_frequencies = {"and":15,  "whale":7,  "frog":7,  "cat":15,  "fish":1,  "dog":2,  "pig":15,  "stork":1,  "rat":15,  "bird":7}

def print_most_frequent(words_dict, word_len):

    keys = words_dict.keys()
    max_length = max([len(i) for i in keys])  # Find max length of words
    min_length = min([len(i) for i in keys])  # Find min length of words

    if not min_length <= word_len <= max_length:
        print("{} letter keywords: [] -".format(word_len))
        return  # Exit function

    words = {i:j for i,j in words_dict.items() if len(i) == word_len}  # Create a dictionary containing words that are the same length as word_len
    max_value = max(words.values())  # Find the max frequency of the words in the above dictionary
    words_final = sorted([i for i,j in words.items() if j == max_value])  # Create a list of words that have the value of max_value 

    print("{} letter keywords: {} {}".format(word_len, words_final, max_value))
```

Output:

```
>>> print_most_frequent(word_frequencies,3)
3 letter keywords: ['and', 'cat', 'pig', 'rat'] 15
>>> print_most_frequent(word_frequencies,4)
4 letter keywords: ['bird', 'frog'] 7
>>> print_most_frequent(word_frequencies,5)
5 letter keywords: ['whale'] 7
>>> print_most_frequent(word_frequencies,10)
10 letter keywords: [] -
```

You may want to clean up the code a bit. But it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your `frequency` variable is probably meant to hold the `maximum frequency`. Your logic about that is wrong, though. If you merge the `>=` and the `!=`, it gives you:

- set `max_frequency` to 0
- if next word's `frequency` is higher than that, add its `frequency` to the `max_frequency`
- repeat last step for all words

Whereas what you actually want, I believe, is:

- set `max_frequency` to 0
- if next word's `frequency` is higher than that, **set** the `max_frequency` to that word's `frequency`
- repeat last step for all words
- find all words with that frequency

Also you only add words to the list which frequency is equal or higher than that of the `frequency`. But I think you want to add all words with the right character count.

---

Long story short:

```
    # filter words based on key length
    right_length = {k: v for k, v in words_dict.items() if len(k) == word_len}
    # calculate maximal value (max frequency)
    max_freq = max(right_length.values())
    # filter words with that max frequency
    max_words = {k: v for k, v, in right_length.items if v == max_freq}
    # now max_words contains all words of specified length with the maximum frequency
    # print words alphabetically
    print(sorted(max_words.keys()))
```

---

Same code in easier:

```
    # filter words based on key length
    right_length = {}
    for k, v in words_dict.items():
        if len(k) == word_len:
            right_length[k] = v
    # calculate maximal value (max frequency)
    max_freq = max(right_length.values())
    # filter words with that max frequency
    max_words = {}
    for k, v in right_length.items():
        if v == max_freq:
            max_words[k] = v
    # now max_words contains all words of specified length with the maximum frequency
    # print words alphabetically
    print(sorted(max_words.keys()))
```

Comment: This helped me out very much, the problem I have now is that there are multiple words with the same amount of length but have different frequences such as "fish":1 and i need to ignore that. I also need to sort it alphabetically so that it goes ['and', 'cat', 'pig', 'rat'] instead of randomising it everytime.

Comment: for sorting wrap the list in `sorted()`. Regarding taking only the animals in which have the highest number, you'd need to calculate the highest number first.

Comment: updated answer with conditional in-line dict creation. With the code above you' have a step-wise filtering system. First you filter out all words of the right length, then you filter out those with the maximal frequency. In the resulting dictionary you have only words with `max_freq` as value.

Comment: If you can edit so that it goes:
    for k,v in words_dict.items():
        if len(k) == word_len:
            right_length = {k,v} 
or something so that it is easier to figure out. I have only learnt basic code for python so the code you gave me isn't easy for me to figure out.

Comment: What if the you try to find a letter with the length 10 but it does not find one and instead it returns an empty list. How do I do that. So that if I try to find a word with the length 10 it returns: 


7 letter keywords: []